# What is this last name that looks like Kennet?

Tags: palaeography, marriage-records, austria, german-language

I'm trying to read this name, that I have written twice in this image (underlined in red):
[image]

My current working theory is Maria Kennet.

This is a marriage record from the Austrian Empire and is recorded in German by the local Catholic church parish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure the last name is Kurent.

I have looked for this name in My Heritage and have found out, that "Kurent" is a Slovenian or Croatian name. There I have found a lot of people with this name.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure it reads "Kurret".

Comment: Note that another GEDCOM I found is giving Kurent.